# Modify DataTables warning: JSON data from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two question on Datatables plugin.
1. When ever I have something wrong with the database I get this error on my page which doesnt seem to be a friendly error. I want to modify it to custom error display when there is a problem from the database or due to expired session. Can I know how do I modify that on my client side using javascript or something.
2. I need to make all the rows in a column or multiple columns to be a hyperlink so that if I click on that link I have some details.

I really appreciate the help from experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatables allow you three ways to solve question 2

1. Modify sever side to get hyperlinks
2. Use fnRender function to build hyperlink on-the fly
3. Use mDataProp as function to build hyperlink only in view

Difference between 2 and 3  is in the last case you will get a powerful tool to modify data by your needs

Comment: Thanks, I have been looking for a sample example of mDataProp and I could not find anything useful.. Can you give a good example, since I am newbie and still in the learning curve..

Answer (score 1):

For question one - you may ask DataTables to throw an exception rather than display an alert. Then you could catch it and handle gracefully,

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.sErrMode = 'throw';
```

for expanation, see:

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/8763/disable-error-reporting/p1

Comment: Can you give me an example of handling that error. I am a newbie learning javascript and datatables, jquery.

Comment: i it's up in their documentation, but this definitely doesn't work for me.